# How to wait for full name to enter in a text box in protractor

Tags: automation, protractor, automated-tests, ui-automation

I am entering a text in a text box using send keys but it is not waiting for text to get entered completely and clicking next button so text is not written completely. How to resolve this issue?

I an entering random name by using date function and appending a constant before this as shown. Now when it enters through sendkeys, first time it gets entered fully like a45 but second time it is entering like a and clicking next button hence test case is getting failed.

How to wait protractor to let the text written completely?

```
var text = 'a' + date.getHours(); + date.getMinutes();

element.sendKeys(text);
element.click();
```

Expected results: a345

Actual: a

Can someone help me in this case and tell me how to make protractor wait for text to be written completely and then click next button?

Comment: Hey. Do you just start writing automated scripts for the app or you're continuing working with existing project? There are two ways to approach to your problem and the solution will depend on your answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

Writing this as async / await. Setting a `browser.sleep` will just add time to your test without knowing if the value is correct. You could use a `browser.wait` instead which will poll for a condition to be true or to timeout (in this case, 5 seconds). The condition we are going to satisfy is if the value attribute is equal to the text.

Note: I changed `element` since that refers to a global object to `someButton` and `someTextBox`.

```
const text = 'a' + date.getHours(); + date.getMinutes();

// send the text    
await someTextBox.sendKeys(text);

// poll for a condition to be true or to timeout of 5 seconds
await browser.wait(async () => {
  // keep checking until the value attribute reflects the entered keys
  return (await someTextBox.getAttribute('value')) === text ;
}, 5000);  

await someButton.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
var msg ='a' + date.getHours() + date.getMinutes();

await element.sendKeys(await msg);
await elemnet.click();
```

Try using async/await. For ref https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/async-await.md

Hope above inputs help you.

remove `;`from `date.getHours();` in your code to get what your are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
var date = new Date();
var hour = date.getHours();
var min = date.getMinutes();
var text = 'a' + hour + min;
```

and then wait for element to get inserted

```
browser.driver.sleep(500);
element.sendKeys(text);
element.click();
```

Comment: A timeout here would not be ideal. Maybe use browser.wait

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an await to your actions so that you wait for the promise to complete.

You could also add a check at the end of a custom send keys method that waits for the send keys to be complete.

```
await elem.clear();
await elem.sendKeys(keys);
return (await elem.getAttribute('value')) === keys;
```

Comment: Leaving some lines of code which may be correct without any explanation is strange. Please include relevant description of what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: @KamilCuk I usually agree but here it's pretty clear and I'm not sure what I can add that would be any more descriptive. I'll update my answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have some good answers here already but if they do not work one thing that helped me on a previous project was to split the string and enter character by character.

```
text.split('').forEach(char => {
  element.sendKey(char);
});
```